# Build JAR with a dependency from the custom repository

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to build a JAR artifact which requires a custom dependency from the bintray repository, like:

```
    https://dl.bintray.com/foo/bar
```

Is it possible to instruct the project that consumes such a library that it should resolve dependencies in the extra repository?

Or should I take another approach to provide it?

Comment: This is supposed to work out of the box in both, maven and gradle. Indirect dependencies will be resolved recursively. Or do you mean at run time?

Comment: @Henry I've build .jar, published to the Gradle Plugins repository and set it as a dependency in the aside project - it cannot resolve such Bintray dependency.
If I set there that repository URL directly, it's fine but that's not the point.

Comment: In Maven, to use a library you need to know both its coordinates (GAV) and the repository it should be resolved from.

Comment: @JFMeier I know that coordinates and repository for the library that I've created, but I have no knowledge about its dependencies - which is Bintray.

Comment: If I follow the comments correctly, you're publishing a plugin to the Gradle Plugin Portal and this has a dependency to a library to be found in your extra repository only?

Comment: @thokuest Correct.

Comment: @hsz Would you mind to update the question accordingly? This is an important piece of information which has some implications ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Build a fat jar including your dependencies.

**Long Version**

Yes, it is *potentially* possible to instruct a project that consumes your Gradle plugin to download plugin dependencies from a non-default repository. But it requires the user intervention which is probably not what you want to hear.

The following **settings.gradle** should retrieve your plugin from the [Gradle Plugin Portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/) and resolve the dependencies from your Bintray repository:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.bintray.com/foo/bar'
        }

        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

This is documented under [Plugin Management](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management).

Please note that I'm a bit vague in my answer since I never did something similar. What I can tell is that the [spring-cloud-contract](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.x/multi/multi_gradle-add-gradle-plugin.html) plugin does exactly this for snapshot versions.

IMHO, in your specific case, you get the best user experience by building a fat jar that includes your dependencies. A remarkable companion being the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/). It also features [additional functionality](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/plugins/) for Gradle plugins, should you ever need them.

Comment: I did it preparing a fatJar with Shadow. Thanks for the additional explanation!